# Could you explain me Why causes Compilier Error?

Tags: java, constructor

```
package Test1;
class DemoParent{
    DemoParent(int a){

    }
}
class DemoChild extends DemoParent{ // Compilier Error

}

public class App {
    public void main(String[] agrs){

    }
}
```

1: Could you explain me Why causes Compilier Error?

2: Could you show me more about inhertance of Constructor from parentClass? 
(childClass also includes Constructor of parent class as normal method, field ?)

Thanks All

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "childClass also includes Constructor of parent class as normal method, field ?" - no, constructors aren't inherited. That's precisely what causes the error. I suspect if you search for the text of the error (which you should include in your question) you'll find duplicate questions on Stack Overflow which explain this in more detail.

Comment: You do not get "compiler error", you get _a specific error_.

Answer (score 0):

Points to understand here :

-Since you have defined a parameterized constructor in the parent class , you need to include a constructor in the child class also , with first line as super(some int). Why this is needed and this is only causing the compilation issues. 
   -If you would have not defined parameterized constructor in parent class or default constructor(without parameters), then there would have been no need to include the super keyword in child class constructor , because by default , when child class extends from parent class , it defines a default constructor for you with first line as super() .

Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a default constructor to the superclass `DemoParent` without a `parameter`.

```
class DemoParent{
    DemoParent(int a){

    }

    DemoParent(){

    }
}
class DemoChild extends DemoParent{ // Compilier Error

}
```